# Problem retrieving user input from second pop up dialogue for Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so I'm trying to learn how to use Tkinter and was trying to make something like a GUI. I created some entry functions and a button that opens up another window for additional data entry. Problem is when I try to assign those values to a variable, there seems to be some issue with the classes. It would say `"Additional" object has no attribute "ttag"`.

My script looks something like this so far

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import *

class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="...").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="...").grid(row=2)

#input fields for tags
#add as needed
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)

        self.b1 = Button(master, text = "Add More", bg= 'grey', command=lambda: Additional(master))
        self.b1.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = self.e1.get()
        second = self.e2.get()

        self.tag = (first, second)
        self.tag1 = (first)
        self.tag2 = (second)

class Additional(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="...").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="...").grid(row=2)

#add as needed
        self.en1 = Entry(master)
        self.en2 = Entry(master)

        self.en1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.en3.grid(row=2, column=1)

        return self.en1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        fir = self.en1.get()
        sec = self.en2.get()

        self.ttag = (fir, sec)
        self.ttag1 = (fir)
        self.ttag2 = (sec)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
d = Initial(root)

toor = tk.Tk() 
toor.withdraw()
e = Additional(toor)

sandwiches = str(d.tag1)
crepe = str(d.tag2)

pic3 = str(e.ttag1)
cap3 = str(e.ttag2)

print(pic3)
```

I think the problem is right here. Since i'm assigning values like e.ttag1, I thought that it would be necessary to have e = Additional(toor) but this also creates a new window. I suspect all my issues would be resolved if there was a better way, any ideas please?

```
toor = tk.Tk() 
toor.withdraw()
e = Additional(toor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you open `Additional` via a button in `Initial`, therefore you should not create another instance of `Additional`.  Also you should not have more than one instance of `Tk` as well.

Below is a modified code based on yours:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        tk.Label(master, text="...").grid(row=1)
        tk.Label(master, text="...").grid(row=2)

        #input fields for tags
        #add as needed
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(master)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(master)

        self.b1 = tk.Button(master, text="Add More", bg='grey', command=self.open_additional)
        self.b1.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # initialize required fields so that they exists even user clicks `Cancel` button
        self.tag = self.tag1 = self.tag2 = None
        self.additional = None  # required if additional data is required

        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def open_additional(self):
        self.additional = Additional(self)

    def apply(self):
        first = self.e1.get()
        second = self.e2.get()

        self.tag = (first, second)
        self.tag1 = first
        self.tag2 = second

class Additional(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        tk.Label(master, text="...").grid(row=1)
        tk.Label(master, text="...").grid(row=2)

        #add as needed
        self.en1 = tk.Entry(master)
        self.en2 = tk.Entry(master)

        self.en1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.en2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # initialize required fields so that they exists even user clicks `Cancel` button
        self.ttag = self.ttag1 = self.ttag2 = None

        return self.en1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        fir = self.en1.get()
        sec = self.en2.get()

        self.ttag = (fir, sec)
        self.ttag1 = fir
        self.ttag2 = sec

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

d = Initial(root)

sandwiches = d.tag1
crepe = d.tag2

if d.additional:
    pic3 = d.additional.ttag1
    cap3 = d.additional.ttag2

    print(pic3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For extra windows, use TopLevel():

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

tk.TopLevel(root)
```

Comment: If I needed access to individual inputs, would something like ``` e = tk.TopLevel(root) ``` work instead?

Comment: What do you mean by individual inputs?